# How would I use PIL to "extend" an image, and then draw a black rectangle with text on it?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Basically, what I want to do with Pillow is:

I want to get an image, and then extend the size of the image from the bottom so I'm able to fit a black rectangle with a four digit code on it. How would I do this? I tried to, but my text ended up being, for some reason, extremely small and unreadable and my rectangle wasn't perfect.

If it makes it easier, here's my image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9eYr.jpg

And here's what I want the end result to be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ4uu.jpg (take a look at the bottom of the image)

Comment: Please click [edit] and insert your latest/greatest code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [ImageOps.expand](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html) to expand your canvas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps

# Load image
im = Image.open('o9eYr.jpg')

# Define font size, and annotation and height of padding above and below annotation
fontSize   = 130
annotation = "GVVL"
padding    = 20

# Load font and work out size of annotation
font = ImageFont.truetype("/System/Library/Fonts//Menlo.ttc", fontSize)
tw, th = font.getsize(annotation)

# Extend image at bottom and get height and width of new canvas
extended = ImageOps.expand(im, border=(0,0,0,th+2*padding), fill=(0,0,0))
w, h = extended.size

# Get drawing context and annotate
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(extended)
draw.text(((w-tw)//2, h-th-padding), annotation,(255,255,255),font=font)
extended.save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there's a way I could increase the brightness of the text I added here? (The 'GVVL' text)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new black image, paste the desired image and add text.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw    

base_img = Image.open('tmp.jpg')
base_size = base_img.size
new_size = (base_size[0], base_size[1] + 150)
img = Image.new("RGB", new_size)
img.paste(base_img, (0, 0))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("microsoftsansserif.ttf", 145) # (<font-file>, <font-size>)d
draw.text((base_size[0] // 2 - 150, base_size[1]),"GVVL",(255,255,255),font=font) # (x, y),"text",(r,g,b)
img.save('out.jpg')
```

Result:

[image: Result]